# How to get Parquet row groups stats sorted across multiple files with Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

My process is creating as outcome multiple parquet files. In my specific case 64 as the number of final partitions. Single file is around ~400MB divided by 3 row groups of ~128MB each one. If I look at single file, every row group has own stats min/max which is well distributed per column. For example, given a `long` column that has for one file (part-00000-*):

```
- group 1 - min:102 max: 9992
- group 2 - min:9994 max: 21990
- group 3 - min:22098 max: 35764
```

and the same column on the next file (part-00001-*) with similar distribution

```
- group 1 - min:99 max: 9882
- group 2 - min:9980 max: 21979
- group 3 - min:22018 max: 32764
```

for a total of 2 files.
What I need is having a distribution like

```
part-00000-*:
- group 1 - min:99 max: 8662
- group 2 - min:8994 max: 13986
- group 3 - min:14333 max: 19845

part-00001-*
- group 1 - min:19877 max: 25621
- group 2 - min:25654 max: 30091
- group 3 - min:31094 max: 35764
```

How can I get that when writing files in PySpark? I know I can simply sort by `df.orderBy('longColumn')` but that affects performance too much so I am looking for an alternative.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean with the distribution to be consistent across the whole set of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming more or less uniform distribution of values within your `longColumn`, perhaps a [`repartitionByRange`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartitionByRange.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartitionByRange) followed by [`sortWithinPartitions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sortWithinPartitions.html) would be a better strategy.

```
df.
  repartitionByRange(64,"longColumn").
  sortWithinPartitions("longColumn",ascending=True).
  write.parquet("myFile.parquet")
```

This way, you'll avoid collecting and sorting the whole dataframe on one executor.

Comment: I tried your solution in place of the `orderBy` and it works better performance wise for what I saw so far.

Comment: Cool. Side note-- per [Parquet docs](https://parquet.apache.org/docs/file-format/configurations/), multiple row groups within a file is bad for _read_ performance. So if your files are 400MB, perhaps you can increase a block size `parquet.block.size`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by making sure you have a global ordering on that column before you write your file. Let's say your dataframe is called `df` and your long column is called `longColumn`.

Then you do something like:

```py
df.orderBy("longColumn").write.parquet("myFile.parquet")
```

If you then check the min/max values for your row groups in `longColumn` you will see you have what you just described.

Comment: Thank you, that was my first thought too but it impacts too much on performance in my case.